# Exercise of central limit theorem, and inequalities.

Tags: probability, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

> A teacher in probability knows that the qualification of a student in his final exam is a random variable $X$ with $E[X]=75$.
>
> a) Find a superior upper bound for the probability of the student be greater than $85$.
>
> b) If the professor knows that the variance is $25$, what can you say about the probability of a student get a qualification between $65$ and $85$?
>
> c) How many students have to do the exam in such way that, with probability at least $0.9$, the average of the ratings will be $75$ in less than $5$?

For a) I find a upper bound with Markov's inequality.

For b) I use Chebyshev inequality:

$$P(|X-E(X)|\geq\epsilon)\leq\frac{Var(X)}{\epsilon^2}.$$

But for c) I don't know how to start. Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: (a) does not give a variance making Chebyshev's inequality difficult. Markov's inequality might work. (b) does not look a natural fit for the central limit theorem, which related to the average of a large number of samples.  (c) does not make a lot of sense to me.  Is the question stated correctly?

Comment: So sorry, I messed up. The c) I think it's referred to how many students must do de test for $P(|X-75|<5)=0.9$ with X the average of the marks from the exams.